# Get the image formats in a Strapi GraphQL query

Tags: graphql, gatsby, strapi

I have a `Post` content type, which has a `FeaturedImage` field. Because this field is an image upload, Strapi generates handy additional formats: `thumbnail`, `small`, `medium` and `large`.

When I query all posts in JSON, I get these formats in the response:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "Title": "Hello World",
  "Content": "Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit..",
  "FeaturedImage": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "angel-jimenez-168185",
    "alternativeText": "",
    "caption": "",
    "width": 2768,
    "height": 1560,
    "formats": {
      "thumbnail": {
        "hash": "thumbnail_angel_jimenez_168185_aaceac7acf",
        "ext": ".jpeg",
        "mime": "image/jpeg",
        "width": 245,
        "height": 138,
        "size": 6.22,
        "path": null,
        "url": "/uploads/thumbnail_angel_jimenez_168185_aaceac7acf.jpeg"
      },
      "large": {
        "hash": "large_angel_jimenez_168185_aaceac7acf",
        "ext": ".jpeg",
        "mime": "image/jpeg",
        "width": 1000,
        "height": 564,
        "size": 75.71,
        "path": null,
        "url": "/uploads/large_angel_jimenez_168185_aaceac7acf.jpeg"
      },
      "medium": {
        "hash": "medium_angel_jimenez_168185_aaceac7acf",
        "ext": ".jpeg",
        "mime": "image/jpeg",
        "width": 750,
        "height": 423,
        "size": 41.8,
        "path": null,
        "url": "/uploads/medium_angel_jimenez_168185_aaceac7acf.jpeg"
      },
      "small": {
        "hash": "small_angel_jimenez_168185_aaceac7acf",
        "ext": ".jpeg",
        "mime": "image/jpeg",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 282,
        "size": 19.69,
        "path": null,
        "url": "/uploads/small_angel_jimenez_168185_aaceac7acf.jpeg"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, if I query in GraphQL, only the `publicURL` for the original (full size) image is available:

[image: GraphQL image format tree]

How I access these image formats with GraphQL?

Answer (score 3):

This query is showing me all of the expected formats objects:

```
query MyQuery {
  strapi {
    home {
      content {
        image {
          formats
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I did explicitly install the graphql plugin on strapi
https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/plugins/graphql.html#usage

and I am using /graphql in my api url (e.g. http://localhost:1337/graphql).

I hope that helps, @jgthms

FYI
strapi v.3.1.4
strapi-plugin-graphql v.3.1.4

Comment: Is there a way to get a specific image format?

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same issue today and have tried to solve this for admittedly too long. It seems that the issue is that when querying is that "formats" is of type JSON and it won't let it be queried. I'm not really sure why this is happening or how to resolve it though. Any advice would be helpful.